# Laravel 5.4 Combining two collections

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I Have two collections, `sales` and `costs`.

Now I need them to combine into one collection for my `foreach` condition *(I'm not sure if I can use two collections in one `foreach`)*

RAW Queries:

```
//Raw MySQL Queries for Sales
$total_sales = DB::raw('SUM(receipts.total) as totalSales');
$year_receipt_created = DB::raw('YEAR(receipts.created_at) as year');

//Raw MyQSL Queries for Cost of Goods Sold
$total_cost = DB::raw('(SUM(qty * cost)) as totalCost');
$year_sold = DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) as year');
```

Here's my `query` for these two `collections`:

```
$sales = DB::table('receipts')
            ->where('status', 'served')
            ->where('mode', 'restaurant')
            ->select($total_sales, $year_receipt_created)
            ->groupBy('year')
            ->get();

$costs = DB::table('orders')
            ->where('status', 'served')
            ->select($total_cost, $year_sold)
            ->groupBy('year')
            ->get();
```

**Things I've tried testing:** Converting the collections into array and tried merging them but I seem to have problems.

I reverted it because I don't know if it's the best way or not. Please let me know what's the best way.

**UPDATE:** Here's the output for those two queries, hope it helps:

**Sales**

```
{
    totalSales: "960.00",
    year: 2017
}
```

**Costs**

```
{
    totalCost: "792.00",
    year: 2017
}
```

What I tried: (It says it cannot find totalCost)

```
//Combining TWO collections into ONE Array
$gross_profit = array();
foreach (array_merge($sales, $costs) as $data) 
{
    $keys = array('total_sales', 'total_cost', '$year');
    $values = array($data->totalSales, $data->totalCost, $data->year);
    $gross_profit[$data] = array_combine($keys, $values);
}
```

**SOLVED: ** I used `collection merge` *(didn't knew there was such a thing)*

The syntax I used is, `$result = $sales->merge($costs)`.

Here's the result:

```
{
    totalSales: "960.00",
    year: 2017
},
{
    totalCost: "792.00",
    year: 2017
}
```

Answered by: [Sagar Gautam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6708661/sagar-gautam)

Comment: Can you add output of `$sales` and `$costs` please.

Comment: @SagarGautam Edited my original post. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: `I seem to have problems` - what problems? What exactly did you try?

Comment: Have you tried collection merge ? like `$result = $sales->merge($costs)`

Comment: And please add expected result as well

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Added the method that I did in the last part.

Comment: *What I tried: (It says it cannot find totalCost)* i assume, you hit this when you tried to print an `Sales` instance.

Comment: @SagarGautam It worked! Added the result and syntax into the original post. Thank you bro, how can I upvote your comment tho? xD

Comment: @JanArielSanJose Any way congrats :D then  I'll add this as answer :v :v

Comment: @SagarGautam Please do, haha. You deserved it.

Comment: @JanArielSanJose Ha  Ha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use collection `merge()` function like

```
$result = $sales->merge($costs);
```

You can see docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-merge

Comment: Thank you! Just to make sure, calling data inside the blade would be like: `$result->totalCost`, `$result->totalSales`, `$result->year`?

Comment: Yeah, but with `foreach` it might give error because in first one there is no `totalCost` and in second one there is no `totalSales`

Comment: Ohhh boy, I think I'll have problems. :o I'll try to ask again after 90 mins, we managed to combine them anyways. :D

Comment: Are you working in E Commerce project all questions of yours are like order sales cost .. etc :D :D

Comment: I'm developing a Generic POS and Inventory System applicable for both Restaurants and Retailer. It has bunch of settings so it'll be flexible. These past previous questions is needed for my _Sales Reports_. It surely hurts the head. :D

Comment: @JanArielSanJose Wow, Some accounting application will always give damn problems at the back end with debit and credit. I've worked in similar application before xD